# Connected Sum Decomposition of a Knot

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, computational-complexity, knot-theory, computational-topology

Given a composite knot, is it possible to decompose it in prime knots by an algorithm that runs in polynomial time?

Comment: What is your motivation for this? And what is your understanding of the situation up until now?

Comment: My understanding of present knowledge is that the answer is it's not known, but highly doubtful that such an algorithm exists. 

Comment: I think current run-time estimates for known algorithms to construct the prime decomposition of a knot tend to be at least exponential. I'm thinking of normal surface theory arguments. 

Comment: A straightforward comment is that this problem is at least as hard as recognizing the unknot. (Given a diagram D for knot, form a larger diagram as the "connected sum" of D with a trefoil diagram. The larger diagram represents a composite knot iff D represents the unknot.)

Comment: I know that in computational topology, there are several softwares like SnapPea and Regina, designed to help topologists in the resolutions of hard problems. I am studying knot theory in this period and then i would like to know if it is possbile (thanks to these programs or other softwares) to decompose a (non prime) knot by an algorithm that runs in polynomial time!

Comment: It's not impossible for there to be such a polynomial-time algorithm, at least with our present understanding of topology.  I think some people have some hope for such an algorithm but we're conceptually at least one major step away from such.  My initial guess is that the most robust procedure you could use at present would be to try to recognise the knot group as an amalgamated free-product.  It wouldn't be an algorithm but I believe with basic small-cancellation theory this would be fairly effective, most of the time.